# Android: Send polyline from android app to external voice navigation map and navigate based on polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I know about

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d" +
  "&saddr="+ srcLat + ","+ srcLong + "&daddr="+ destLat + "," + destLong));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK & 
  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
  "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Here I am adding source and destination lat and long. Instead of lat and long I want to send polyline to external navigation map and navigate based on polyline.

Answer (score 0):

you can't. The above code does the navigation using google maps application that calls the server API. In order to do what you want, you'd need to modify google maps.

Comment: Can you elobarate how can i modify google maps or can i add voice navigation in my own application @Dorigatti

Comment: well, you can't modify google maps, unless you are in google :D
If you instead want to add voice navigation in your app, well you have to do everything, and I don't have examples on how to do that (You 'just' have to write a navigator app...)